# Jooq AddCondition method with Select Query

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Here is my problem I am trying to add a Select query in where condition how can i achieve this in Jooq?

```
selectQuery.addFrom(DefaultInfo.DEFAULT_INFO);
selectQuery.addConditions(DefaultInfo.DEFAULT_INFO.FOLDER_TYPE=+"(Select FolderType From Folder Where Folder.FolderRSN = folderRSN )" );
```

I know this is wrong but how to add a Select Query output in another query where condition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [`Field.in(Select<? extends Record1<T>>)`](http://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org/jooq/Field.html#in%28org.jooq.Select%29) method on your column. For example:

```
DEFAULT_INFO.FOLDER_TYPE.in(
    select(FOLDER.FOLDER_TYPE)
   .from(FOLDER)
   .where(FOLDER.FOLDER_RSN.eq("folderRSN"))
)
```

The `IN` predicate is documented in the manual, here:

- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/in-predicate/
- http://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/conditional-expressions/in-predicate-degree-n/